# C# calling stored procedure with OLEDB connection not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, oledb

I have a stored procedure which read data from eExcel file, when executing this stored procedure, it works well and read all the data and fill the SQL table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Importdata2
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(50)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [' + 'Sheet1' + '$]'

    INSERT INTO Branches (Description)
    EXEC (
            'select distinct  Department 
     FROM OPENROWSET(
    ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0''
     ,''Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=' + 'C:\ATTapp\ATToutput files\test.xls' + ';HDR=YES''
     ,''' + @sql + ''') where Department not in (select description from Branches)'
            )
END 
GO
```

I need to call this stored procedure from C# code like this:

```
try
{
    using (DBConnection con = new DBConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ImportData2", con.Connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    Logger.log("Error in Importdata function:" + err);
}
```

The problem is when calling this stored procedure from C#, it returns a SQL exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)". OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   SimpleAttendance.frmLogin.CallImportDataSP(String filetype, String
>   filepath, String query) in c:\Users\Amal\Desktop\Attendance
>   app\SimpleAttendance\SimpleAttendance\SimpleAttendance\frmLogin.cs:line
>   127 ClientConnectionId:3758d5ca-1589-4bff-a006-f9e93dafce8b Error
>   Number:7303,State:1,Class:16}

Comment: Check if the `C:\ATTapp\ATToutput files\test.xls` file exists on disk. Also, are you sure file extension should be `.xls` and not `.xlsx` for Excel 12.0 driver?

Comment: the file Exists. I executed the stored procedure from SQL and its working normally. but when i call it from C# code it gives this error !!

Comment: Can you try from C# with the escaped file path in SQL: `C:\\ATTapp\\ATToutput files\\test.xls`? Also, do try it from C# with .xlsx file extension.

Comment: I tried it with 2 backslashes and xlsx but also not working same error  :(

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your spT code to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Importdata2
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''
    DECLARE @sqlFull NVARCHAR(max) = ''

    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [' + 'Sheet1' + '$]'
    SET @sqlFull = '
            INSERT INTO Branches ([Description])
            select distinct  Department 
     FROM OPENROWSET(
    ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0''
     ,''Excel 12.0;Database=' + 'C:\ATTapp\ATToutput files\test.xls' + ';HDR=YES''
     ,''' + @sql + ''') where Department not in (select description from Branches)'

    print 'Full SQL: ' + @sqlFull
    EXEC (@sqlFull)
END
GO
```

I've moved `EXEC` out of the `INSERT INTO` and now feed `EXEC` with complete dynamic SQL string.

If you get syntax errors, notice what print statement prints. Try this version with both `.xlsx` and `.xls` files. Note, the Excel file should exist on disk before you actually run your spT. Note, I've also removed `Xml` from the `OPENROWSET` connection string because in my `OPENROWSET` calling code which works I don't have it.

Comment: Same error! the execution of the sp works normally on sql but when i call it from C# code it gives the same error

Comment: @Malo that is really strange. However, I do suspect it is something to do with the actual Excel file. Maybe permissions? Can you move the Excel file to some `C:\temp` folder where Everyone has read-write access?